# How to draw arc under words (LaTeX)?

Tags: xetex

I'm using the `devanagari` package in LaTeX to incorporate Hindi/Sanskrit alphabet. Is there a way to draw an arc under words?

A basic example would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{devanagari}

\newcommand{\arc}{...}

\begin{document}
  \arc{{\dn saaregama}}
\end{document}
```

To generate a PDF document:

1. Save the above document as `example.dn`.
2. In the terminal run `devnag example.dn`.
3. This generates a file `example.tex`.
4. Run `pdflatex example.tex` to generate a PDF.

Without the `\arc{}` command, the PDF generated would be: [image: input image]

With the `\arc{}` command, the PDF generated would be: [image]

If I have `\arc{ABCD}`, then it should ouput the following:

[image]

Is there any way to do this

1. Within `devanagari` package?
2. If not within, then using some package that doesn't conflict with the `devanagari` package?
3. If not, then by defining your own way to do it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se Since you're asking about compatibility with a specific package, it would be extremely helpful to provide a minimal compilable document using that package that people could test with.

Comment: Unrelated, but for Indic scripts, you're probably better off using XeLaTeX and `polyglossia` and entering your source directly.

Comment: Thank you @AlanMunn, I have added a minimal working example.

Comment: The arcs package (https://ctan.org/pkg/arcs?lang=en) seems to do what you want. However, when compiled with XeLaTeX it doesn't work properly. If you are not using XeLaTeX maybe that helps you :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}

% usage: \uarc[sep][depth]{text}
\NewDocumentCommand\uarc{O{.2ex} O{.3ex} m}{%
    \tikz[baseline=(arced node.base)]{
        \node [inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (arced node) {#3};
        \draw [transform canvas={yshift=-#1}] (arced node.south west) parabola [parabola height=-#2] (arced node.south east);
    }%
}

\begin{document}

Look, it's an \uarc{arc}!

Look, it's a \uarc[-.1ex]{long arc}!

\end{document}
```

[image: output of the code above]

You can of course adjust the default values for the separation and the depth of the arc to your liking.

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly what you're asking, but you can try the `\underbracket` command, from `mathtools`, or  `\undergroup`, which comes from `mathabx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathabx} 

\begin{document}

$\underbracket[0.6pt][0.7ex]{\textsf{\,ABCD\,}}\qquad\undergroup{\textsf{\,ABCD\,}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `devanagari` package doesn't work in math environment unfortunately, but thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Even with the command `\text{...}`?

Comment: Works with `\text{...}`, thank you.

Comment: Very nice answer. +1.